# how to convert python file into exe with images and libraries

Tags: python, exe

```
root = tk.Tk()
img = PhotoImage(file=f'C://Users/{os.getlogin()}/downloads/monitor.png')
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)
root.title('                                                                                                                        Screen Recorder')
root.geometry('+260+70')
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)
st_icon = PhotoImage(file=f'C://Users/{os.getlogin()}/downloads/rec.png')
sp_icon = PhotoImage(file=f'C://Users/{os.getlogin()}/downloads/stop.png')
cam_icon = PhotoImage(file=f'C://Users/{os.getlogin()}/downloads/webcam0.png')
com_icon = PhotoImage(file=f'C://Users/{os.getlogin()}/downloads/webcam1.png')
shot = PhotoImage(file=f'C://Users/{os.getlogin()}/downloads/screenshot.png')
```

This is my code and I have 6 icons that I want to include in that exe file plus I have multiple libraries that I want to include in this.

My main motive is that anybody should able to run this file on any computer without installing all those libraries if that is possible.

Comment: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/

Comment: Change the hard coded paths `PhotoImage(file=f'C://Users/{os.getlogin()}/downloads/rec.png')` because its not portable.

Comment: @devp should I replace the path and write the file name only( after moving the files to same folder

Comment: Create a folder with any name and its should be inside of your project and use relative path instead of absolute path please read  
 https://support.dtsearch.com/webhelp/dtsearch/Relative_Paths.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyinstaller to create an exe. But you need to include all the files in the same folder as the exe.

```bash
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.ico main.py
```